# opengles 2.0 per-vertex lighting

Tags: opengl-es

VertexShader:

```
varying vec4 diffuseColor;
uniform mat4 modelViewProj;
uniform mat4 modelViewTranspose;
attribute vec3 streamNormal;
attribute vec3 streamPosition;
void main() {
    gl_Position = modelViewProj * streamPosition;
    diffuseColor = max(0, dot(normalize(modelViewTranspose * streamNormal), vec3(0,0,1)) * vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

PixelShader:

```
varying vec4 diffuseColor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = diffuseColor;
}
```

the matrix is by left-hand (row major), modelViewProj calculated by C++, it is the world * view * projection, modelViewTranspose = transpose(inverse(world * view)).

The render result is not right, I cannot see any thing, but if I set gl_FragColor always to vec4(1,1,1,1), the model render is no problem. Does my code have errors? or other problems?

Comment: What are the colors of your objects? The `diffuseColor` calculation in the vertex shader is only showing the red component due to the final multiply by `vec4(1,0,0,1)`. If your colors are all blues and greens, you won't see anything. Also, are your object normals facing towards or away from the camera? If they're all facing the wrong direction, then you also won't see anything.

Comment: Wait, is `modelViewProj` really row-major? Or are you saying that you transposed it after calculating it? If you passed it to OpenGL as a row-major matrix then you need to reverse the order of the matrix and vector multiplication: `gl_Position = streamPosition * modelViewProj;` In Desktop GLSL you can actually tell GLSL that a matrix uniform is row-major using a layout qualifier, but GLSL ES does not support this, so your only option is either to transpose the matrix or do what I showed you (they have the same effect mathematically).